# Cypress and ngx-scrollbar with auto-height

Tags: angular, cypress

I am testing an application which uses [ngx-scrollbar](https://github.com/MurhafSousli/ngx-scrollbar/) with auto-height ([autoHeightDisabled: false](https://jsrepos.com/lib/shhdharmen-ngx-scrollbar-indicator)). My tests clicks on something which is sometimes still invisible to the user, because a parent of the element, the `ng-scrollbar` element, is currently adjusting its height. But `:visible` matches and `should('be.visible')` is true. My workaround is a `wait(100)` before doing the click. But this is considered [bad style](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Unnecessary-Waiting). It looks like this:

```
    // eslint-disable-next-line cypress/no-unnecessary-waiting
    cy.get('#foo:visible').wait(100).click();
```

Any idea how to do this right?

To clarify: The test is able to click on the element without the `wait`. The problem is kind of a cosmetic one: The screenshots look bad. The test step in the Cypress GUI looks bad.

Comment: Cypress uses the DOM. As long as the element is in the DOM it'll find it, regardless of wether it's visible to the user. I think your problem lies elsewhere, but it's hard to tell with no code provided.

Comment: @DFSFOT I am sure that in that moment `ng-scrollbar` is not heigh enough to visibly fully contain the element under test. But yes, it is in the DOM under its parent. The test can click on it. But the screenshot looks bad. The test step looks bad. That’s the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, the tests where still flaky. We got rid of the problem by adding a `min-height` CSS property to `ng-scrollbar` e.g.

```
ng-scrollbar {
    min-height: 425px;
}
```

or whatever minimal height is needed to include the elements to be clicked on.